# C# Elasticsearch-NEST Escape WhiteSpace Character

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I want to escape whitespace character in querystring. 
My code is

```
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        const string indexName = "evaluationdev5";
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
            node,
            defaultIndex: indexName
        );

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var indexExist = client.IndexExists(indexName);
        if (!indexExist.Exists)
        {
            var response = client.CreateIndex(indexName);
        }
        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = "1",
            Firstname = "john smith",
            Lastname = "hendrick"
        };
        var person2 = new Person
        {
            Id = "2",
            Firstname = "smith john",
            Lastname = "hendrick"
        };
        client.Index(person, x => x.Index(indexName));
        client.Index(person2, x => x.Index(indexName));
        var result = client.Search<Person>(s => s
            .Explain()
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
                .QueryString(qs => qs
                    .OnFields(new[]{"firstname","lastname"})
                    .Query(@"joh*\ smith")
                    .DefaultOperator(Operator.And)
                )
            )
        );
```

Person class is

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

My querystring is **joh*\ smith**. And i want to result only "John Smith". But result is empty. 
Also i try with quotes querystring **"joh* smith"** still result is empty. 
What can i do this querystring ?

Comment: i m not sure on what you want do to ... if you can explain more the result wanted i can help you

Comment: @dzomba, I want to escape whitespace character. So, in query string i write "joh*\ smith". Result must be only "John Smith".  Also i try with quotes querystring "\"joh* smith\"" still result is empty.

Comment: I don t get it. Why don t use john smith ?? What type of analyzer did u used ?